# Default username and password for *.example.com

Tags: mac, passwords, keychain, username

I have a bunch of dev domains that are all subdomains of example.com e.g. test1.example.com, test2.example.com etc

They all use HTTP authentication and the same username and password. Is there a way of adding a wildcard username and password to my mac keychain?

Comment: So, no control of the type of HTTP Authentication?

Comment: Nope, sorry it is what it is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keychain and Safari's built-in password manager does not support wildcards, as far as I know.

An alternative would be [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password), a third-party password manager that integrates with Safari, Firefox, and other browsers and does support wildcards. (Actually, it will offer to autofill a password for any subdomain of the domain associated with the password.) It's not as simple or straightforward to use as what's built in, but is definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

> They all use HTTP authentication

If that is HTTP *Basic* Authentication then I think you're out of luck (and your credentials are sent in an insecure way when not using HTTPS). But, if it is [HTTP *Digest* Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) then you can fix it on the server, assuming you can control those development servers and have a limited number of domains.

For Apache see directive `AuthDigestDomain` in [`mod_auth_digest`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html):

> The specified URIs are prefixes; the client will assume that all URIs "below" these are also protected by the same username/password.
> [..]
> The URIs specified can also point to different servers, in which case clients (which understand this) will then share username/password info across multiple servers without prompting the user each time.

(See also `domain` as defined in "3.2.1 The WWW-Authenticate Response Header" of [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617). See also [Apache .htaccess trick to authenticate only once for all subdomains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62843/apache-htaccess-trick-to-authenticate-only-once-for-all-subdomains) on Stack Overflow. Note that old versions of IE [have some issues](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#msie).)

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and filed a bug on Firefox for this. Surprised it wasn't filed already: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589628