# Firefox: save username/password for all sub domains?

Tags: firefox, passwords, wildcards, subdomain

Not sure if this is possible -- I have a username and password combo which is valid for all sub-domains of a given domain, that is: `domain1.example.com`, `domain2.example.com`, `domain3.example.com`, etc. Is there any way I can tell Firefox that the saved password for one of these subdomains is valid for all of them? RIght now I have been retyping it for each one, and saving them individually. But the list of these subdomains will be constantly growing...

Comment: See "Default username and password for *.example.com" at http://superuser.com/questions/49543/default-username-and-password-for-example-com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using firefox addon called LastPass. This addon recognizes that subdomains and prompts you to use previously saved password.

LastPass is also a third party service which stores your password in 128bit encrypted cloud server. Your passwords never leave your system. Passwords are encrypted on system and then sent server.

hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was hoping for a built in way but it looks like there's not. I suppose this would eliminate Firefox's annoying habit of asking me for my master password 10,000 times. Thanks!

Comment: "LastPass is also a third party service which stores your password in 128bit encrypted cloud server"  -   then the next sentence:   "Your passwords never leave your system. "     These can't both be right.    Also: a 128 bit encryption is not necessarily very strong either.   Thanks, I'd rather store them locally.

Answer (score 7):

I filed a bug for this on Firefox. Surprised it wasn't filed already: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589628

Comment: Incredible, I still cannot use it nearly five years later. Due to Opera (which has a decent password manager) giving up on Presto, I decided finally to switch to Firefox and get to see plenty of shortcomings already in the first few hours. The new Opera versions would be even worse, though.

Comment: Opera is using Chromium as Chrome does and both cannot remember passwords on subdomain. Pretty eftup, if you ask me, as a lot of sites running their password protected client support on subdomain.

Comment: **NEWS!** This is slated t be fixed in FF 71. Check the bug for details.